# Ruling on covering the tooth with gold or silver?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh

Is it good or permissible for a pilgrim after his pilgrimage to change or cover one's tooth with gold or silver metal?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Fiqh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ja'fari_jurisprudence) of [Shia Islam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shia_Islam) if gold is used to cover tooth for purpose of beauty it is Haram for men (but permitted for women) in any condition (in prayer or not prayer, in Hajj or not Hajj). Only in necessary medical purposes it is allowed for men.

About silver there is no limitation in any condition.

---

**References:**

- [Online answering](http://makarem.ir/websites/english/?p=oas) of [Official website of Grand Ayatollah Makarem
  Shirazi](http://www.makarem.ir/)